# How to properly set VoIP Innovations credentials in RestComm AMI?

Tags: voip, amazon-ami, restcomm

I'm having troubles setting up the API username/password from VoIP Innovations in my RestComm AMI.
I've followed the steps described [here](http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-configure-ami-for-voip-innovation/) but the `AvailablePhoneNumbers` api call returns an empty list.

Then I accessed the instance via ssh and checked for the restcomm.conf file in the standalone folder. My VoiceRSS key was there but the not the VI credentials. I spent some time looking at the other files in `$RESTCOMM_HOME` and I found one of particular interest: `$RESTCOMM_HOME/bin/restcomm/autoconfig.d/config-restcomm.sh`

In that file the `configVoipInnovations` method call was commented and even if it wasn't commented it requires a third argument (the VI endpoint ID, which I'm not sure if it refers to the VI Endpoint Group ID or something else) that wasn't mentioned in the link above.

I also tried editing `$RESTCOMM_HOME/standalone/deployments/restcomm.war/WEB-INF/conf/restcomm.conf` directly with

```
<voip-innovations>
    <login>my VI Api username</login>
    <password>my VI Api password</password>
    <endpoint>my VI endpoint group id</endpoint>
    <uri>https://backoffice.voipinnovations.com/api2.pl</uri>
</voip-innovations>
```

But it didn't seem to work. The `AvailablePhoneNumbers` still returned an empty list.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@nbermudezs,

Sorry that you are having problems configuring Restcomm for Voip Innovations. When you are using Restcomm AMI, it already comes pre-configured with a default (Demo) Voip Innovation account that will automatically provision DIDs and allow you to choose an Area Code in the United States. Because the configuration script will automatically default to the pre-configured Voip Innovations account, modifying the restcomm.xml file will not work work as expected. Did you try to provision DID using the Admin UI?

On the AMI, this is how to set your VI information

Go to the directory /opt/telestax/restcomm/current/bin/restcomm

edit the file restcomm.conf

Go to the section below and fill out your VI account details. The must be set to PROVISION_PROVIDER='VI'

```
# DID Provision provider variable declarations
PROVISION_PROVIDER=''        # values: VI (VoipInnovation), BW (Bandwidth), NX (Nexmo), VB (Voxbone)
#Username and password for all supported DID provision providers
DID_LOGIN=''
DID_PASSWORD=''
# VoipInnovation Endpoint ID
DID_ENDPOINT=''
```

Save your changes

You must restart Restcomm as follows

- restcomm_stop
- restcomm_start

Comment: Thanks for the reply TechKid. I had provisioned DID from the Admin UI. And it works great for voice stuff. But I was trying to make SMS Api calls, following this other [link](http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-api-sms-messages/), and the logs in the Admin UI showed **failed** as the status. At the bottom of the link it says that the **From** must be a SMS enabled DID number but when I try to register one none of the listed have SMS enabled, that why I tried to setup my on VI account.
I'll try the DID_* settings. Let me know if you want me to create a separate question to talk about the SMS

Comment: @nbermudezs, It is up to you if you want to create another post for SMS.

Comment: This answers combined with Pepova's did the trick. Since the original question was related to VI and not the SMS enabled DID, I'll mark this as the accepted answer. But thanks a lot to both of you :)

Answer (score 1):

@nbermudezs,

In order to send/received SMS you should register an SMS enabled DID. Unfortunately you cannot register such DID via the Admin UI (in contrast with voice DIDs). You should go to your VoipInnovations account dashboard and search for SMS enabled DIDs there. Register the SMS enabled DID of your choice first in VoipInnovations back office and then simply go to Restcomm Admin UI -> Numbers -> +Register Number. From the drop down menu choose US as Country, select the area code for the DID of your choice and in the Number field enter the actual number (without the area code in front of it) then click register. After that you should be able to send/receive SMS from/to your newly registered DID.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Although I had to get another DID number in the VI BackOffice since the one I had had 872 as the Area Code which was not listed in the dropdown options in the Admin UI.